# Cosmos DB Collection not using _id index when querying by _id?

Tags: performance, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a CosmosDb - MongoDb collection that I'm using purely as a key/value store for arbitrary data where the _id is the key for my collection.

When I run the query below:

```
globaldb:PRIMARY> db.FieldData.find({_id : new BinData(3, "xIAPpVWVkEaspHxRbLjaRA==")}).explain(true)
```

I get this result:

```
{
    "_t" : "ExplainResponse",
    "ok" : 1,
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "data.FieldData",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [ ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {

            },
            "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
            "executionSuccess" : true,
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 106,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 3571,
            "executionStages" : {

            },
            "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : #REMOVED#
}
```

Notice that the totalKeysExamined is 0 and the totalDocsExamined is 3571 and the query took over 106ms.   If i run without .explain() it does find the document.

I would have expected this query to be lightning quick given that the _id field is automatically indexed as a unique primary key on the collection.  As this collection grows in size, I only expect this problem to get worse.

I'm definitely not understanding something about the index and how it works here.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your MongoDB version? I tried your example with 4.2.2 and it correctly uses the `IDHACK` stage, which is scanning the `_id` index.

Comment: running version() in console shows 4.2.3

Comment: was the IDHACK stage used in the rejected plan?  If so, how long did it take according to the allPlansExecution?

Comment: do I have to set something on the server to get all that info?  the explain() response I posted is exactly what I see.  I don't see anything in rejected plans or allPlansExecution , even if I call .explain("allPlansExecution").     This is a MongoDb database behind Azure CosmosDb if that makes any difference.

Comment: So my guess is that it's something with cosmosdb implementation as it's not truly mongodb server behind the scenes. I may open ticket with MS as they dont appear to support all these diagnostic commands.

Comment: @Adam yes that's your answer. Cosmos DB is Microsoft's implementation of MongoDB API, which means they work very differently underneath.